# IEnumerable to gridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am creating a gridview and need to gather the data from various functions that return a type of IEnumerable.

I've created gridviews using a dataset as a datasource, but how does one use multiple data sources(of IEnumerable) to populate one gridview?  Like how do you combine all that into one dataset?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't bind multiple data sources to a gridview, you would need to combine the multiple data sources into a single collection and bind to that.